# How can you check whether a checkbox is in the indeterminate state (neither checked nor unchecked)?

Tags: cypress

In Cypress you can test whether a checkbox is checked by:

`cy.get('[data-cy=my-selector]').should('be.checked');`

And conversely you can check whether it is not checked by:

`cy.get('[data-cy=my-selector]').should('not.be.checked');`

I can't find a way to check whether the checkbox is in the indeterminate state.

[image]

Is there any way to do that in Cypress?

Comment: Can you share your element HTML when the checkbox is unchecked and when the checkbox is in the indeterminate state ?

Comment: @AlapanDas There is not really a way to make a checkbox indeterminate through html, it is done through javascript. This indeterminate property is one of few properties that have no represention in HTML but are present in the element model. For an example see https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/JYyXjX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jquery property `.is(":indeterminate")` for this. Considering your codepen example. You can do something like:

```js
cy.get('input#tall').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.is(':indeterminate')) {
    //Do something here when checkbox is in indeterminate state
    expect(true).to.be.true //Or, Apply a true assertion
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I just realised that I can do that with a simple css selector:

`cy.get('[data-cy=my-selector]:indeterminate').should('exist');`

Thanks @AlapanDas for pointing that selector out.

Answer (score 3):

Another short way using the `.should` method:

```
cy.get('#checkbox-input')
  .should('have.prop', 'indeterminate');
```

Comment: doesn't test if its true or false tho

Answer (score 2):

Here is another, perhaps more direct, way to check the indeterminate attribute in Cypress:

```
    cy.get('#checkbox-input')
      .invoke('prop', 'indeterminate', true)
```

Comment: From the docs this would `set` indeterminate not check for it. The docs for `invoke` are;

Invoke a function on the previously yielded subject.

@see — https://on.cypress.io/invoke